# CSS/Bootstrap containers

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to have two containers, because when I change the size, it also changes the size of the menu. Here's my index http://paste.laravel.com/GN8, I want this part:

```
     @if ($news->count())
            @foreach($news as $news)
    <div class="container">
<div class="doc-content-box">
        <legend>{{ $news->title }} <div id="spaceholder"></div>

        <p>
          <h6><i class="icon-calendar"></i> {{ $news->created_at }} &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/profile/{{ $news->author }}">{{ $news->author }}</a>
        </p>
      </h6>
      </legend>
        <div style="margin-top:7px">

<p>{{ $news->content }}</p>
    </div>

</div> <!-- /container -->
<div id="spaceholder">&nbsp;</div>
        @endforeach
        @else
    {{ 'There are no news.' }}
@endif
```

be width 749px, when I copy the .container which I added before, it just pulls it to the left.
I want it to be something like `container-two`.

I also have custom CSS that overrides container:
http://paste.laravel.com/JEt

Comment: anyone? haven't solved this.

Comment: Can you give a jsfiddle of your problem with a full HTML output instead of some template?

Comment: @MaximeLorant jsfiddle doesn't work for me, for some weird reason. here's a picture: http://1.imgland.net/R_dRuw.png you see, the navigation bar is not in the center, I've overrided the css with: http://paste.laravel.com/JEE, I want the navigation bar be like width: 1020px but centered (let's say it's container-two), and the container remains 749px centered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the container this styling:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

Comment: it works, that wasn't hard lol. thank you. I can award the bounty in 23 hours, I will:)

Comment: The logic behind this it that block elements (div's for example) are centered when given 'auto' in right and left margin